# How to loop in a xml structure with xquery?

Tags: xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0

the xml is like this:

```
<persons>
<person>
<name/>
<surname/>
</person>

<person index=1>
<name/>
<surname/>
</person>

<person index=2>
<name/>
<surname/>
</person>
...
</persons>
```

I need to build a view that shows all data of all persons.

```
name surname
name1 surname1
```

How can i do this loop in a select statement? It needs to be a view.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a very short XPath one-liner solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
string-join(/*/person/concat(name, ' ', surname), '&#xA;')
```

**when this XPath expression is evaluated, against the following XML document:**

```
<persons>
    <person index="1">
        <name>Alex</name>
        <surname>Brown</surname>
    </person>
    <person index="2">
        <name>Katie</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
    </person>
    <person index="3">
        <name>Julius</name>
        <surname>Caesar</surname>
    </person>
</persons>
```

**the result is**:

```
 Alex Brown
 Katie Smith
 Julius Caesar
```

Comment: +1 This is better answer (not ussing `for`). Consider to use `string-join()` because otherwise you get a sequence, so after the new-line, an space will be added.

Comment: @Alejandro: I am not going to output the result using `<xsl:sequence>`, so I am not concerned about the final appearance. You are right that there are many ways to get the concatenation of the three text nodes without any intervening delimiters. But you are right, anyway -- I have edited my answer with the proposed fix. BTW, Why did you delete your answer? Please, undelete it, I wanted to upvote it for being also correct and short enough.

Comment: Thanks, but ussing a fuction call as last step is better in a functional sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using xslt if you need a transformation?

If you need to xquery, to select these nodes then,

```
doc("file.xml")/persons/person/name | /persons/person/name
```

OR

```
doc("file.xml")//name |// surname
```

i.e. Name, Surname occuring anywhere

Comment: the xml is a column of a table in database. and if i use the xpath: /persons/person/name it will get only the first it finds right?

Comment: May I ask what you are using at the backend?  Asp.NET? Java? PHP? As for your question - No, to my knowledge, It will return a set of matched nodes.